# Share image and link on facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any way to share image and link on facebook in android. I tried below code without success.

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setContentDescription("Simple Test")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://material.io/icons/"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://data.kaktus.media/file/file/2017-12-08_16-29-44_928522.jpg"))
                .build();
```

AFAIK `setImageUrl` is now deprecated. The problem is the `ImageUrl` image is replaced by the `ContentUrl` image as mentioned in this question [FaceBook ShareLinkContent setImageUrl is replaced by ContentUrl metadata in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39020477/8942811).

Comment: You need to add og-tags on the URL you share