# App icon is not showing on Facebook share dialog

Tags: android, image, facebook, url, share

I am sharing my google play store application link from my Android Application to Facebook.

But, facebook ShareDialog only display my app name and does not display app icon in that post.

Here is my code:

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ScoreBoardActivity.this);
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aaa.aaa.aaaa"))
        .setQuote("See if you can beat my sorting score " + score + "!")
        .build();
shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
```

My app is published today.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: did you add icon in the facebook developer console.?

Comment: Yes, there is app icon of 1024x1024 in my facebook developer account.

Comment: append ` .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(your image path)))` in content

Comment: I did that. But, setImageUrl is deprecated and it is not working as well. Also I heard that if you are sharing play store link then you do not need to setImageUrl. Is this true or not?

Comment: don't know too much about it, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39888190/5110595) hope it will help you!

Comment: I already googled a lot but nothing helps. Even I changed app store URL to some existing application on play store which is integrated with facebook and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some problem in your link. Try to change your link from:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aaa.aaa.aaaa
```

to:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aaa.aaa.aaaa&hl=en
```

Just append `&hl=en` at the end of you package name. It works for me.

I faced the same issue few days ago. I don't know this solution will work for you or not but give it a try once. And make sure you have added all the graphics in your facebook developer console.